What is the relationship between work done and force applied?
How can we calculate the work done by an object if we know how much force is applied? What kind of mathematical relationship exists between the two variables?

Force is nonlinearly related to the rate of change of kinetic energy over time, and energy must be expended somehow to exert a force, but that's the only relationship I can think of. What specific "relation" are you referring to for clarification?

@controlgroup Energy must be expended somehow to exert a force. What energy does a proton expend to keep an electron bound to it in a hydrogen atom?

Force is linearly related to the displacement through which it acts.  https://flexbooks.ck12.org/cbook/ck-12-middle-school-physical-science-flexbook-2.0/section/13.2/primary/lesson/calculating-work-ms-ps/

Sorry - thinking of gravity/electromagnetism in the context of gauge field curvature. I meant a force as in something that causes deviations from a geodesic in such a field theory.

Work $W$ is energy, and $W = \vec F \cdot \vec x$, that is, applying a force over a distance (in a vector-> scalar sense) involves energy.
